# Angular Ionic 4 How to pass a Variable correctly with Route

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I want to get a variable form movie-list.page.html  straight to an other subpage called movie-series.

**movie-list.page.html:**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"  [routerLink]="['/movie-series', item.ThemaNr]" detail="false">
      <ion-icon name="albums" slot="start" [style.color] ="item.Farbe"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{item.Name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="list" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What should I do on the subpage 'movie-series' to get the 'item.ThemaNr' - variable there ?
Should I edit the 'app-routing.module.ts  before?
Should I add something into 'movie-series.page.ts' like this? -->

```
constructor (
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  let ThemaNr = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('ThemaNr');
}
```

And how can I access the variable now in movie-series.page.ts?

I'm a little bit confused about routing correctly. The browser gives an error at this point:

**Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'movie-series/2'**

Comment: Can you provide us your routing?

Comment: Did You mean the app-routing.module.ts?  As shown below...

Answer (score 0):

**from app-routing.module.ts -->**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'movie-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./movie-list/movie-list.module').then(m => m.MovieListPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'rss',
    loadChildren: () => import('./rss/rss.module').then(m => m.RssPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'impressum',
    loadChildren: () => import('./impressum/impressum.module').then( m => m.ImpressumPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'movie-series',
    loadChildren: () => import('./movie-list/movie-series/movie-series.module').then( m => m.MovieSeriesPageModule)
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```